# angular $scope digest update from a dom event

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, dom-events

I have an angular $scope variable that gets instantiated through a window event. The $scope variable is displayed correctly to the user, but updates are not being set through ng-model. What's odd is that ng-change has the correct value that I can use to manually set the scope variable.

I really don't understand why this is happening.

Event Handler:

```
document.addEventListener('updateSearchBar', handleUpdate);
function handleUpdate(eventData) {
    $scope.benefitsFromDate = eventData.detail.fromDate;
    $scope.$apply();
}
```

Front end:

```
<input 
    type="date" 
    name="fromDate" 
    ng-change="updateBenefitsFromDate(benefitsFromDate)" 
    ng-model="benefitsFromDate" 
/>
<input 
    type="button" 
    value="Search" 
    class="btn btn-default" 
    ng-click="searchDocuments()" 
    ng-disabled="isSearchingDocuments"
/>
```

Angular snippet:

```
$scope.updateBenefitsFromDate = function(change) {
    console.log($scope.benefitsFromDate); //still has old value
    console.log(change); //has updated value when param is the $scope variable
    //$scope.benefitsFromDate = change; //only way to update
 };

$scope.searchDocuments = function() {
    //ng-model never updates the variable when the value is changed and uses the instantiated value
    console.log($scope.benefitsFromDate);
};
```

Why doesn't ng-model reflect the change, but passing $scope.benefitsFromDate in the ng-change function have the updated value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I learned that angular is finicky about "dot rules".

All I had to do was prefix my data values with something else.

```
$scope.data = {};
$scope.data.benefitsFromDate = ...;
```

Or you can declare your controller to use `as`

```
ng-controller="appController as vm"
```

Answer (score 1):

I use the [`$timeout`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout) module when processing these kind of updates and avoid the call to `$scope.$apply()`.

```
$timeout(function() {
  $scope.benefitsFromDate = eventData.detail.fromDate;
});
```